# How to conversion of Mysql data http calls use Spring cloud data flow?

Tags: java, mysql, spring-boot, redis, spring-cloud-dataflow

I need to implement an ETL-like function to Migrate Mysql Data to another system via http calls. A high degree of real-time data is required in the process

I tried to combine spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-jdbc and spring-cloud-starter-stream-processor-httpclient. Instead, I got spring-cloud-starter-stream-source-jdbc without main class error.

```
jdbc --spring.datasource.driver-class-name=org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver --spring.datasource.username='******' --spring.dataso… | http …
```

Answer (score 0):

At first, I reconstructed it with reference to the https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/source-samples/jdbc-source . I added main class and rabbit binder. The stream is running as scheduled. I didn't think it was supposed to be this complicated, and then I switched to jdbc-source-rabbit, which is exactly what I expected

Comment: Hi, it is not clear whether or not you're still having issues with it. Could you update the post and clarify as to what is actually breaking? Do you see errors? What versions of apps and SCDF are you on? Let's start with this information.